Get vertical cells of a range object
How can I get the cells of a column (only vertical cells) in a Word table?
Note:
I am not interessted in all the cells of a column, there for I can't seem to use .Column.Cells because I would like to ignore the header/footer part of a column, as you will see in the images below I have excluded the first and last row.
The header/footer part could consist of mulitple rows and is not limited to only 1 row. There for I am looking for a "precise" solution, to get all cells in column 2 from row 2 to 7.
If possible I would like to avoid using .Select() and .Selection.Cells.
See the following screenshot illustrating what cells I would like to get.

Currently when I build a Range object from the desired start to the desired end, I am gettting those cells.

Code to build the Range object:
[VBA]
Sub test()
    
Dim t As Table
Set t = Selection.Tables(1)

Dim cellStart As Cell
Set cellStart = t.Cell(2, 2)

Dim cellEnd As Cell
Set cellEnd = t.Cell(7, 2)

Dim cellRange As Range
Set cellRange = ActiveDocument.Range(cellStart.Range.Start, cellEnd.Range.End)


Dim cellsInRange As Cells
Set cellsInRange = cellRange.Cells

MsgBox cellsInRange.Count
    
End Sub

[C#]
private void Test()
{
    var t = Selection.Tables[1];
    var cellStart = t.Cell(2, 2);
    var cellEnd = t.Cell(7, 2);
    var cellRange = ActiveDocument.Range(cellStart.Range.Start, cellEnd.Range.End);
    var cellsInRange = cellRange.Cells;
    Debug.Print(cellsInRange.Cells.Count.ToString());
}


Use the Cells collection of the Column. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.column.cells

@TimothyRylatt - sorry, didn't mention it in the post it self (will update it shortly), but as you can see from the images provided, I am not interested in all the cells of a column I would need to be able to ignore the frist or more rows (header) and to ignore the last or more rows (footer)

So just loop through the collection and ignore the first and last. Otherwise you’ll have to use Selection

@TimothyRylatt - yes, that would be possible though I would prefer a Cells which enables some benefits eg. setting border of type wdBorderHorizontal to change the „inner“ border, or change shading and so on, without having to write custom whats the „inner“ border when going through each individual cell, without the need to set properties, call methods on each individual cell so basically all methods/properties from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cells

Column(item).Cells returns precisely that collection with all properties, methods, etc., i.e https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.column.cells = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cells

@TimothyRylatt - BUT it includes header/footer, my desire is a Cells object without those header/footer rows

Then let me reiterate: So just loop through the collection and ignore the first and last. Otherwise, you’ll have to use Selection
